# Extract a substring between two characters in a string PHP

Tags: php, substr

Is there a PHP function that can extract a phrase between 2 different characters in a string? Something like `substr()`;

Example:

```
$String = "[modid=256]";

$First = "=";
$Second = "]";

$id = substr($string, $First, $Second);
```

Thus `$id` would be `256`

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You can do it in two parts: you firstly get string from $first and then parse the result till the $second character.

Comment: what do you actually want to capture? the id, the string, the = ?

Comment: in such cases i usually love to explode my strings: explode("=",$String); and in a second step i would get rid of that "]" maybe through rtrim($string, "]");

Answer (score 70, accepted):

use this code

```
$input = "[modid=256]";
preg_match('~=(.*?)]~', $input, $output);
echo $output[1]; // 256
```

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/0eD2ns

Comment: For anyone wondering: The reason index `1` of `$output` contains the text matched by the pattern inside the parenthetical is that `$output[0]` is the full text of that is matched by the pattern. `$output[1]` is the text matched by the first sub-pattern; `$output[2]` is the text matched by the second sub-pattern, and so on. See [the official documentation on `preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for more.

Answer (score 28):

Use:

```
<?php

$str = "[modid=256]";
$from = "=";
$to = "]";

echo getStringBetween($str,$from,$to);

function getStringBetween($str,$from,$to)
{
    $sub = substr($str, strpos($str,$from)+strlen($from),strlen($str));
    return substr($sub,0,strpos($sub,$to));
}

?>
```

Comment: Function returns FALSE if not matched.

Answer (score 4):

```
$String = "[modid=256]";

$First = "=";
$Second = "]";

$Firstpos=strpos($String, $First);
$Secondpos=strpos($String, $Second);

$id = substr($String , $Firstpos, $Secondpos);
```

Comment: The third argument to `substr` is `length` not ending position. If you run this, you will see that `$id` is equal to "=256]" here not "256". https://www.php.net/substr

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use reqular expresion, use [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php), [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and [strrev](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) functions:

```
// Require PHP 5.3 and higher
$id = trim(strstr(strstr($String, '='), ']', true), '=]');

// Any PHP version
$id = trim(strrev(strstr(strrev((strstr($String, '='))), ']')), '=]');
```

Comment: be careful, when no `=` or `]` in the `$string` !

Answer (score 2):

Regular Expression is your friend.

```
preg_match("/=(\d+)\]/", $String, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

This will match any number, for other values you will have to adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

```
<?php
$string = "[modid=256][modid=345]";
preg_match_all("/\[modid=([0-9]+)\]/", $string, $matches);

$modids = $matches[1];

foreach( $modids as $modid )
  echo "$modid\n";
```

http://eval.in/9913

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "[modid=256]";
preg_match('/\[modid=(?P<modId>\d+)\]/', $str, $matches);

echo $matches['modId'];
```

Answer (score 0):

*(moved from comment because formating is easier here)*

might be a lazy approach, but in such cases i usually would first explode my string like this:

```
$string_array = explode("=",$String);
```

and in a second step i would get rid of that "]" maybe through rtrim:

```
$id = rtrim($string_array[1], "]");
```

...but this will **only** work if the structure is always exactly the same...

-cheers-

ps: shouldn't it actually be ***$String = "[modid=256]";*** ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Regular Expression

```
$String =" [modid=256]";
$result=preg_match_all('/(?<=(=))(\d+)/',$String,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Output**

Array ( [0] => 256 )

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ar3KRl)**

**Explanation**
   Here its used the Positive Look behind (?<=)in regular expression
   eg (?<=foo)bar matches bar when preceded by foo,
   here (?<=(=))(\d+) we match the (\d+) just after the '=' sign.
   \d Matches any digit character (0-9).
   + Matches 1 or more of the preceeding token

Comment: Why you have used $result variable?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the way to get your string:

```
<?php
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}


$fullstring = '.layout { 

color: {{ base_color }} 

}

li { 

color: {{ sub_color }} 

} 

.text { 

color: {{ txt_color }}

 }

 .btn { 

color: {{ btn_color }}

 }

.more_text{

color:{{more_color}}

}';

  $parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, '{{', '}}');
  echo $parsed;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of good answers here. Some of the answers related to strpos, strlen, and using delimiters are wrong.

Here is working code that I used to find the height and width of an image using delimiters, strpos, strlen, and substr.

```
$imageURL = https://images.pexels.com/photos/5726359/pexels-photo-5726359.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940;

// Get Height
$firstDelimiter = "&h=";
$secondDelimiter = "&w=";
$strPosStart = strpos($imageURL, $firstDelimiter)+3;
$strPosEnd = strpos($imageURL, $secondDelimiter)-$strPosStart;
$height = substr($imageURL, $strPosStart, $strPosEnd);
echo '<br>'.$height;


// Get Width
$firstDelimiter = "&w=";
$strPosStart = strpos($imageURL, $firstDelimiter)+3;
$strPosEnd = strlen($imageURL);
$width = substr($imageURL, $strPosStart, $strPosEnd);
echo '<br>'.$width;
```

Basically, define your string delimiters. You can also set them programmatically if you wish.

Then figure out where each delimiter starts and ends. You don't need to use multiple characters like I did, but make sure you have enough characters so it doesn't capture something else in the string.

It then figures out the starting and ending position of where the delimiter is found.

Substr requires the string it will be processing, the starting point, and the LENGTH of the string to capture. This is why there is subtraction done when calculating the height.

The width example uses string length instead since I know it will always be at the end of the string.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regular expression or you can try this:

```
$String = "[modid=256]";

$First = "=";
$Second = "]";
$posFirst = strpos($String, $First); //Only return first match
$posSecond = strpos($String, $Second); //Only return first match

if($posFirst !== false && $posSecond !== false && $posFirst < $posSecond){
    $id = substr($string, $First, $Second);
}else{
//Not match $First or $Second
}
```

You should read about substr. The best way for this is a regular expression.