# getting no output for while loop in php?

Tags: php

I have been trying to take out some value from a string in php but not getting success so if you people can please take a look at my code as :

```
$html = "[ect]afdbec[ect]";
$output =true;
$x=1;

while ($output == true) {
$pos = strpos($html,"[");
$value = substr($html,$pos,$x);
echo $value;
$x++;
if ($value == "]") { $output = false; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the line `$pos = strpos($html,"[");` outside the `while` loop. Because, it initializes the value of `$pos` to the position of `"["` in each iteration of the loop. I don't think it will solve this problem.

Please get used to [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). There will be a lot more simple way to do it.

Please try:

```
$html = "[ect]afdbec[ect]";
preg_match('~\[(.*?)\]~', $html, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891743/extract-a-substring-between-two-characters-in-a-string-php) also

Comment: Thanks...it really helped...where can I learn `preg_match` patterns?

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue might be that you're checking when `$value` is equal to "]" (in the if-statement), but $value will never be just one character; you're asking it to always `substr()` from the position of the first "[".

You might want to have a look at `preg_match()` - there's a slight learning curve if you're new to it, but it'll help with this situations in future development.