# PHP regex incorrect

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract all strings that look like `12-15` from a parent string. This means all strings that have a dash in between two digits.

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14891816/3040381) answer as a basis, I tried the following:

```
<?php

$str = "34,56,67-90,45";
preg_match('/^(\d-\d)|(,\d-\d)|(\d-\d,)|(,\d-\d,)$/', $str, $output, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo print_r($output);

?>
```

This looks for any substring that looks a dash enclosed between digits, whether it has a comma before, after, or both, or none. When I run the PHP code, I get an empty array. On Regex101, when I test the regular expression, strings like `4-5,,,,,` seem to, and I'm not understanding why it's letting me add extra commas.

What's wrong with my regex that I get an empty array?

Comment: Why are you using `echo` and `print_r` on the same line? `print_r` already prints the array, you don't need to call `echo`.

Comment: @Barmar it was a mistake, I usually add `true` after `print_r()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\d` matches a single digit. All the numbers in your sample string have two digits. You should use `\d+` to match any number of digits.

```
preg_match('/^(\d+-\d+)|(,\d+-\d+)|(\d+-\d+,)|(,\d+-\d+,)$/', $str, $output, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ,67-90
            [1] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => -1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ,67-90
            [1] => 5
        )

)
```

You can also simplify the regexp:

```
preg_match('/(?:^|,)\d+-\d+(?:,|$)/', $str, $output, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ,67-90,
            [1] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: How would I extract ALL instances of the pattern into the array?

Comment: Use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`.

Comment: The flags for `preg_match_all` are a bit confusing. I just wanted an array where I can iterate through with the matches found in the parent string. It seems as though, if I use the flag `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` and do `preg_match_all($str, $output, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);`, `$output[0]` is the array I'm looking for. I've done a few tests, and they seem to be consistent. To make sure, am I correct about this?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And I agree, the options are a bit confusing, I can never remember which way is the default.

Comment: Your regex fails when there are consecutive pairs of numbers `34,56,67-90,34-53,24-23` https://regex101.com/r/kO2iD7/1

Answer (score 4):

I think you could use a simple regex like this

```
\d+[-]\d+
```

That is (match at least 1 digit) (match a literal dash) (match at least 1 digit)

Answer (score 1):

The `|` has precedence, meaning your expression is interpreted as "MATCH EITHER ONE OF THE FOLLOWING:

1. START of text -> 1 digit -> dash -> 1 digit (not matching end of text)
2. Comma (may be in the middle of the text, anywhere) -> 1 digit -> dash -> 1 digit
3. 1 digit (anywhere) -> dash -> 1 digit -> comma
4. comma (anywhere) -> 1 digit -> dash -> 1 digit -> comma -> END of text

Also, your are using `\d` which matches 1 digit (only one character). You can use `\d{2}` to match 2 digits (00 to 99), or `\d+` to match any integer (1, 55, 123456, etc).

---

In your case, I think you're trying to use this expression:

```
/(?:^|,)(\d+-\d+)(?=,|$)/
```

which means: START of text OR comma -> any integer -> dash -> any integer -> followed by (but not consuming inmatch) a comma OR END of text

Comment: Your regex fails when there are consecutive pairs of numbers `34,56,67-90,34-53,24-23`

Comment: True. I was mislead by the use of preg_match instead of preg_match_all. EDITed in answer with a lookahead. Thanks