# Regex expression meaning?

Tags: regex

I am trying to learn regex and came across this question: [Extract a substring between two characters in a string PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891743/extract-a-substring-between-two-characters-in-a-string-php) for which one of the answers has:

```
    $input = "[modid=256]";
preg_match('~=(.*?)]~', $input, $output);
echo $output[1]; // 256
```

I am guessing `~=(.*?)]~` can be broken down into saying 'find the thing between `=` and `]` ' but what do the `~` mean and how are they used in general? (I have looked in other places but can't seem to find a meaning for this symbol)

Comment: It's called a tilde. Perhaps you did not know that when you were searching. Google tends to remove the weird characters in your searches, but if you write the word "tilde" I am sure you will find something.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ye your right, actually I wouldn't have called that a tilde, I tend to associate tildes with things that go above letters rather then a stand alone character.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification. I used to think that when I studied French. Now I study computers more, so my bar for what I consider to be a proper tilde has moved down.

Comment: The tilde is used to match in RegEx. The 2 operators '~' and '!~' perform regex comparisons.