# How to Get the word of a string from select area php

Tags: php

I have Three word . But i need only those word which is in { } 
Like:

```
text1 {text2} text3
```

get the text only in { }

```
Result = text2
And
result = text1 text3 (remove {} word )
and
from text1 {text2} text3 {text4}
result = text2 and text4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract a substring between two characters in a string PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891743/extract-a-substring-between-two-characters-in-a-string-php)

Answer (score 1):

Try [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) for this :

```
$a = 'text1 {text2} text3';
 preg_match_all("/\\{(.*?)\\}/", $a, $matches); 
print_R($matches[1][0]);
```

output will be:

```
text2
```

Comment: I need two more result 
`result = text1 text3 (remove {} word )`
and
from text1 {text2} text3 {text4}
`result = text2 and text4`

Comment: @AshikKaiser check `$matches` array for `$a = 'text1 {text2} {text3}';` it will return you 'Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {text2}
            [1] => {text3}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => text2
            [1] => text3
        )

)'

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be loop through each character.
If character is {
then start collecting characters into word variable.
If you find } character, then finish - you have a word.

Comment: preg_match or preg_match_all is better. Less memory consuming and thus faster.

Comment: If memory and speed is the problem, then yes. Otherwise, for me readability is more important.

Answer (score 0):

with regex:

```
$search = 'text1 {text2} text3';
preg_match('#\{(.*)\}#', $search, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

see [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) doc