# To get values between two words using awk or sed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have to get the value between the two "key" words using either awk or sed or if it is some other tool also I am fine. I have tried below code, I am not getting the desired output.

```
echo "<response status = 'success'><result><key>LUFRPhdfhhfufhroghyuefbFJyaEkwamhjMnRxVW9ZWT1854165442156744ZiZlljbjlHSlBjNXgwMzVJcz0=</key></result></response>" |  awk -v FS="key" 'NF>1{print $2}'
```

Output I expect is:

```
LUFRPhdfhhfufhroghyuefbFJyaEkwamhjMnRxVW9ZWT1854165442156744ZiZlljbjlHSlBjNXgwMzVJcz0=
```

Comment: Looks like XML, and if so you'd better use an XML parser. Anyway with GNU sed : `sed -En 's@.*<key>(.*?)</key>.*@\1@p'`

Comment: Look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891743/extract-a-substring-between-two-characters-in-a-string-php/14891816

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably best to use an xpath expression here:

```
echo '<response status="success"><result><key>LUFRPhdfhhfufhroghyuefbFJyaEkwamhjMnRxVW9ZWT1854165442156744ZiZlljbjlHSlBjNXgwMzVJcz0=</key></result></response>' | \
xmllint --xpath '/response/result/key/text()' -

LUFRPhdfhhfufhroghyuefbFJyaEkwamhjMnRxVW9ZWT1854165442156744ZiZlljbjlHSlBjNXgwMzVJcz0=
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fix your field separator `FS`:

```
echo ... |  awk -v FS="(<key>|</key>)" 'NF>1{print $2}' 
LUFRPhdfhhfufhroghyuefbFJyaEkwamhjMnRxVW9ZWT1854165442156744ZiZlljbjlHSlBjNXgwMzVJcz0=
```